# protractor exiting before getting a value from the DB (or I am not sure what happens)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, protractor

```
var usercoll = db.collection("users");
usercoll.findOne({email: config.registered.email}, function (err, user) {
    console.log("after first find one");
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return
    }
    helper.registerUser("anewuser", function () {
        browser.sleep(2000).then(function () {
            usercoll.findOne({email: email}, function (err, newuser) {
                console.log("after find one");
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return
                }
                ;
                console.log(newuser);
            });
        })
    })
}
```

I can see "after first find one" in the console.

I can never see the output "after find one" in the console, and the tests just returns as if it worked, no error and success message.

But I am doing more stuff afterwards, and it seems it's never called. Why that? Is there some synchronization issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a promise and make it to wait till the script finds the new user,

```
var usercoll = db.collection("users");
var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
usercoll.findOne({email: config.registered.email}, function (err, user) {
    console.log("after first find one");
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return
    }
    helper.registerUser("anewuser", function () {
        browser.sleep(2000).then(function () {
            usercoll.findOne({email: email}, function (err, newuser) {
                console.log("after find one");
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return
                }
                ;
                console.log(newuser);
                defer.fulfill(newuser);
            });
        })
    })
}

defer.then(function(newUserDetails){
    console.log(newUserDetails);
})
```

Comment: hmmm interesting @Sudharsan, does this mean I have to write promises for *every* async call I am making? I am having awful results currently, due to me not using promises at all and using async code all over the place. It seems my scripts always terminate before the actual "expect" actually return anything, luring me that the tests succeeded.

Comment: Yeah. to make all your asynchronous calls to be sync with your script, you need to use promises.

Comment: ok thanks. I will review it all, my script is quite big, and report, and accept when confirmed. Thanks!